# C++ Read txt and put each line into Dynamic Array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to read input.txt file, and trying to put each line into the array as string (later on I will use each element of array in initializing obj that's why I am putting each line into the array).

```
    string* ptr = new string;
    
    // Read Mode for Input
    fstream input;
    input.open("input.txt", ios::in);

    int size = 0;

    if (input.is_open()) {
        string line;
        while (getline(input, line)) {
            cout << line << endl;
            ptr[size] = line;
            size++;
        }
        input.close();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
        cout << "array: " << ptr[i] << endl;
    }
```

I am getting error as:

> Proxy Allocated, drain it

Comment: `ptr` is a single dynamically allocated `std::string`. Since you're using the standard library anyways, just use `std::vector`: `std::vector<std::string> fileContents; ... while(getline(input, line)) { fileContents.emplace_back(line); }`; otherwise you'd need allocate new arrays move the old contents and destroy the old ones yourself; much simpler to just let `std::vector` do the heavy lifting for you here...

Comment: I understand thank you for your answer, so If i want to go without vectors I need one extra array which will hold old memory?

Comment: `string* ptr = new string;` Becomes `string* ptr = new string[number_of_strings_in_file];`. Getting `number_of_strings_in_file` is the challenge because you won't know how many `string`s you need in the array until after you have read the file. `vector` handles this for you. In the absence of `vector` the best thing to do is write your own simple version of `vector`. If this is an assignment and the instructor said, "Do not use `vector`", that often translates to "Whoever solves this problem by writing a `vector` class gets top marks."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use arrays; use `std::vector`.  The `std::vector` behaves like an array and uses Dynamic Memory:

```
std::string s;
std::vector<std::string> database;
while (std::getline(input, s))
{
    database.push_back(s);
}
```

Keep it simple. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As was noted in the comments, if you don't know how many lines in the file then you need a container which grows on request at runtime. The natural choice is [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) :

```
std::fstream input("input.txt", std::ios::in);

std::vector<std::string> lines;
std::string line;
while (getline(input, line)) {
  lines.push_back(line);  // std::vector allocates more memory if needed
}

for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
  std::cout << lines[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The while statement will include the if input.is_open. The if statement is redundant.

Comment: True. correcting, @CaptainGiraffe